# Handle parent events in child user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a .ascx user control in a parent .aspx. In the parent I have a dropdown and I am able to access that dropdown from the child by doing this:

```
MonthYear = Me.Parent.Controls(2).FindControl("MonthYearPicker1")
```

I would also like to access the "MonthYear" events from the child just like I would from the parent e.g.:

```
Protected Sub MonthYear_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectedEventArgs)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Better handle the event in the parent page and _call_ a method of the user control.

Comment: Well its not the solution I had hoped for but I did end up calling a method in the user control from the parent:

Answer (score 0):

Well its not the solution I had hoped for but I did end up calling a method in the user control from the parent:

```
Dim fpr As HRBudgetReports_FPRReport = New HRBudgetReports_FPRReport
fpr.GetMonth() 'Method in user control
```